# Google maps API: how to get all cities in an administrative area

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocode

I don't know if it is possible but I would like to get the list of cities which are in a specific country and in a specific administrative area of this country.

I found how to retrieve a city with a specific postal_code like this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:FR|postal_code:34000

Now i would like to the same with an administrative area but this doesn't return the list of cities, it just returns latLng of the administrative area:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:FR|administrative_area_level_1:Languedoc-Roussillon

I didn't found a solution anywhere.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The API will not provide you with a list of cities. What is a *city*? A village? A certain-sized town? You can try to find lists of cities depending on certain criterias, along with their coordinates, then you can check if they fall within specific bounds. Look at Fusion tables. You might find useful data. Example:  https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1TJk4Fh8AU5IIhMDmvJOhcAOu9I5EB6xu9uKxI30#rows:id=1

Comment: If you need I can provide you with a list of over 87000 cities around the world, along with their coordinates.

Comment: This is the problem, I just wanted a server that can gives a list of cities for a specific administrative area because I don't want to overload my database with a lot of citites. If it is not possible with Google Maps API then I will try another way. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I find myself around a similar request and won't mind that list of yours. If you can, please send it to bahmed@live.com. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @BabatundeAhmed that was a long time ago. It seems quite easy to find this kind of data set nowadays. For example [here](https://github.com/lutangar/cities.json).